# http2:info (70007)The timeout specified has expired: client x.x.x.x:xxxxx AH02950: h2_session(2): error reading, terminating

Tags: apache, http2

I successfully installed an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt using certbot. My website seems to be running without any problem.
My server is Ubuntu 16.04 on Apache/2.4.18. I installed http2 module and it seems to work fine.

But, when I check my Apache error.log, I get tons of messages like these :

```
[Fri Sep 08 14:43:05.714366 2017] [http2:info] [pid 2129] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 195.221.155.11:56932] AH02950: h2_session(6): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:44:35.424938 2017] [http2:info] [pid 1559] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 178.149.169.177:35524] AH02950: h2_session(3): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:45:44.538785 2017] [http2:info] [pid 32149] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 80.215.162.154:28341] AH02950: h2_session(20): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:48:43.594498 2017] [http2:info] [pid 1331] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 90.28.109.155:51857] AH02950: h2_session(1): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:48:44.456602 2017] [http2:info] [pid 2129] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 78.192.12.171:50312] AH02950: h2_session(6): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:49:04.443087 2017] [http2:info] [pid 2141] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 178.50.64.162:27963] AH02950: h2_session(24): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:49:04.443166 2017] [http2:info] [pid 2631] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 178.50.64.162:17882] AH02950: h2_session(26): error reading, terminating
[Fri Sep 08 14:50:28.678586 2017] [http2:info] [pid 2582] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 37.18.174.227:16896] AH02950: h2_session(11): error reading, terminating
```

I've noticed that when I display any page of my website with my browser, the page displays well, but about 5 minutes after that I have this error message in the log.

Does anybody knows how to stop my error.log screaming like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Apache to a later version.

See this bug for example: https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/72

There were a lot of changes to mod_http2 since 2.4.18 and it only dropped the "experimental" status in 2.4.26. See this answer for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/840827/should-we-use-apaches-http2

Comment: Thank you so much. When upgrading to apache 2.4.27, I encountered this error :
`[http2:warn] [pid 25095] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.`
So I disabled mpm_prefork and enabled mpm_event with fastcgi